# Determine List.IndexOf ignoring case

Tags: c#, list

Is there a way to get the index of a item within a List with case insensitive search?

```
List<string> sl = new List<string>() { "a","b","c"};
int result = sl.IndexOf("B"); // should be 1 instead of -1
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Try this :** So there is no direct way to use IndexOf with String Comparison option for LIST, to achieve desire result you need to use Lambda expression.

```
int result = sl.FindIndex(x => x.Equals("B",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score -6):

The IndexOf method for Strings in C# has a ComparisonType argument, which should work something like this:

```
sl.IndexOf("yourValue", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

or

```
sl.IndexOf("yourValue", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Documentation for this can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As @c0rd said in response to another answer for this thread, this isn't about a `string`, it's about a `List<string>`.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I downvoted that answer too. I hope there are no hard feelings. Just trying to help.

Comment: This answer was useful for me..I upvoted it.